# Account as top level directory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are a lot of articles in the net about dealing with subdomain accounts in Rails. See [this](http://robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/01/11/subdomain-accounts-with-ruby-on-rails-explained) for example. However, I cannot find a simple way of making an account key as the top-level directory of the url. That is, I want to convert my

http://account.domain.tld url to

http://domain.tld/account

So far, the best all-around gem I've come so far to dealing with this is [routing filter](http://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter/tree/master).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to look at [Subdomain_fu](http://www.intridea.com/2008/6/23/subdomainfu-a-new-way-to-tame-the-subdomain?blog=company).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a custom route with a [wildcard component](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#wildcard-components). Add something like this to **config/routes.rb**:

```
map.account ':/account', :controller => 'accounts', :action => 'show'
```

Then in `AccountsController`:

```
def AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def show

    # Probably move this into a before_filter
    @account = Account.find_by_name(params[:account])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in the controllers, or perhaps even on the servers vhosts (Apache or Nginx or whatever). Here's an example that uses controllers.

```
# App controller
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :monitor_subdomains

  private

  def monitor_subdomains
    return if !request.subdomains.empty? && !request.subdomains.first != "www"

    account = request.subdomains.first
    redirect_to "#{account}/#{request.request_uri}"
  end
end

# routes.rb
map.account ":account_name" do |account|
  account.resources :projects
  # more account related routes...
end
```

I'm not sure if my routes.rb example will work, but you get the picture.